# php mkdir permission issue

Tags: php, apache, shell, centos

CentOS 7, php5.4 - shell access.

/home/toms/public_html/..

all folders and files under /home is toms:toms and 755

myuser got ALL priv in visudo.

Issue:

In php script when trying to mkdir(/home/toms/public_html), 0755, true);
receive Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in...
I tried going to 777 but still no work. Also tried change all files to root but didn't work.

echo `whoami`; -> apache

How can I change so 'whoami' is toms, which I believe is the best solution.

P.S. Well aware of php old version, but no upgrade possible at this point.

Comment: The User in your case is apache,which is trying to create the directory and hence getting Permission Denied Error.

Comment: Right. So how can I change user 'apache' to user 'toms'?

Answer (score 1):

Trying changing ownership to apache user. As its CentOS, it should be `apache` and give owner-write permission.

```
sudo chown apache:apache /home/toms/public_html/
chmod 0755 /home/toms/public_html/
```

Comment: chown www-data:www-data gives me:

chown: invalid user: 'www-data:www-data'

Comment: I have updated my answer for CentOS. You can get the list of all available users by `cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd`. Make sure `apache` is one of them.

Comment: sudo chown apache:apache /home/toms/public_html/ did not help. Also tried to do same change recursively.

I did add apache to to the toms group and toms got visudo ALL but still no go.

Should also mention that php is run through the apache API, not CGI.

Answer (score 0):

Permission issue fixed:

In /usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service

set PrivateTmp=false (it's set to true by default)

finish up:

systemctl daemon-reload

systemctl restart httpd